# Calculating the Area by Square Feet with Geopandas

Tags: coordinate-system, area, geopandas, python-3

I have a `geodataframe` that has no assigned `crs`. I want to create a column/field called 'area' that has the area calculated as square feet, not meters or km, using geopandas. **Note:** this `geodataframe` was created by doing an attribute join between 2 previous geodataframes that had the projection: `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

```
[38]: print(bldgs_merged.crs)
      None
```

Something like this:

```
bldgs_merged["bldg_sqft"] = bldgs_merged['geometry'].area/ 10**6
```

I know that the crs/projection first needs to be in a crs/projection that uses square feet. My question is, what projection do I set it to? Will WGS 84/EPSG 4326 work? Do I have to do something to set the units to be square feet?

```
bldgs_merged = bldgs_merged.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `area` attribute of a GeoDataFrame is calculated based on projected coordinates not latitude and logitude, this means that the area you are calculating is false.

First you need to reproject the GeoDataFrame to a different CRS which units is either meter or feet, and then measure the area using `area`attribute.

PS: `EPSG:4326` is using degrees as units, try the `EPSG:3857` which uses meters as unit or if you know the location of your polygons choose a projection from a national grid

Comment: Question. This seemed to work, but the calculation of the area from the geometry is returned as dtype: float with a nonsensical value like `7.338585e-09`. Does this look right? How would I convert this to a 2-digit `double`?

Comment: @gwydion93 you can round the result to 2 digit by using a lambda function `gdf['rounded_area'] = gdf['area'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))`